# I want to have different value in columns and rows. Values can repeat but not thrice

Tags: arrays

I want my GRID of 9x9 to have different values in range of 1-5
Its generating values but i am getting same values together three times

For Example 
3 3 5 5 3 4 5 3 2 
5 1 1 1 1 5 5 3 5 
5 1 2 2 5 4 4 2 3 
1 3 1 4 4 3 2 1 2 
5 2 1 5 2 1 4 2 5 
2 5 3 1 3 5 4 4 2 
1 5 5 4 3 2 2 1 3 
3 1 2 5 1 2 1 1 2 
3 2 4 5 3 3 3 4 2

Values are repeating three times together

My Code :

int GridArr[9][9] = { 0 };

```
srand(time(0));
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        GridArr[i][j] = 1 + rand() % ((5 + 1) - 1);
        if (GridArr[i][j] == GridArr[i+2][j] || GridArr[i][j] == GridArr[i][j+2])
        {
            srand(time(0));
            GridArr[i][j] = 1 + rand() % ((5 + 1) - 1);
        }
        cout << GridArr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's not a homework question. Actually, it's a project-related question. Developing a small C++ Game through SFML Graphics library and the game is of Candy Crush type. @outis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, repeating values are perfectly normal in a random sampling. There's a lot of academic research on the true nature of randomness, and what humans consider to be random is not very random at all. If you're interested, read up on stochasticity.

In any case, for your particular case, I understand you do not want >2 repeats either vertically or horizontally, right?

First off, you'll need to check the 2 previous values both horizontally and vertically. In your code, you seem to be looking forwards (i+2 and j+2) instead of backwards, in other words you're comparing with values that haven't been set yet. Furthermore, you're only checking the value two squares ahead, not the values of both squares ahead.

It looks like you're coding in c++, right? I haven't coded in c++ for a very long time, so this might not be the most efficient way of doing things, but I added a check in your code for "forbidden numbers" (either 2 horizontally or vertically previously) and added those values to a map. Then I passed that map to the number generator which picked from an array of values including all numbers except those in the map. Hope that makes sense!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int getRandomNumber(map<int, bool> forbiddenNumbers);

int main()
{
    int GridArr[9][9] = { 0 };
    
    srand(time(0));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            // this map will keep track of which numbers we don't want for this grid position
            map<int, bool> forbiddenNumbers;
            
            // check horizontal
            if (i > 1 && GridArr[i-2][j] == GridArr[i-1][j]) {
                forbiddenNumbers[GridArr[i-2][j]] = true;
            }
            // check vertical
            if (j > 1 && GridArr[i][j-2] == GridArr[i][j-1])
            {
                forbiddenNumbers[GridArr[i][j-2]] = true;
            }
            
            // pass map of forbidden numbers to number generator
            GridArr[i][j] = getRandomNumber(forbiddenNumbers);
            cout << GridArr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int getRandomNumber(map<int, bool> forbiddenNumbers) {
    int allowedValues[5 - forbiddenNumbers.size()];
    
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        if (forbiddenNumbers.count(i) > 0) {
            // if this number is forbidden, don't add it to the allowed values array
            continue;
        }
        allowedValues[pos] = i;
        pos++;
    }
    
    // return a value from the allowed values
    return allowedValues[rand() % pos];
}
```